# ngFor data with pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I need to use data in item and filter it type while loop. but look like angular 2 pipe can't do this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items| filteritem: item.type ">
```

Do angular 2 have way to filter item while in loop ?

Comment: yes angular 2 have item in a loop you code should work, what kind of error r you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter" (keyup)="0" />
<ul><li *ngFor="let item of items | filteritem:filter)">{{ item | lowercase }}</li></ul>
```

and in your Pipe filter the data by Type:

```
transform: function(value, args) {
               if(!args) return value;
               var filter = args.type.toLocaleLowerCase();

               return filter ? value.filter(element => element.type.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) : value;
           }
```